# extracting public key from private key dynamically using M2Crypto

Tags: python, rsa, m2crypto

is it possible to extract public key from private key in pem format in python, with something like M2Crypto?
I want to same thing happen like when you use this command:

> openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -pubout > mykey.pub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M2Crypto.RSA` has `load_key` function which returns an `RSA` object which has `save_pub_key` method.

```
from M2Crypto import RSA
RSA.load_key('mykey.pem').save_pub_key('mykey.pub')
```